# Decoding Anchor Tag in String

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a string returned from a 3rd party API, that contains fully formed anchor tags (on most occasions). The html appears to be fully formed and correct.

I want to decode this and output into an MVC view as a valid anchor tag, however HTMLDecode does not seem to convert the anchor tag into a link.

I am simply outputting the text as such;

```
<p>@HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Description)</p>
```

but the text comes out with anchor tag included, like this;

```
This is a test description. Check here - <a href="http://query.nytimes.com/gst/fullpage.html?res=9F0DE2D81E3CF936A25753C1A9669C8B63&sec=&spon=&pagewanted=all">New York Times</a> for more information
```

Am I expecting to much of HtmlDecode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `@Html.Raw()`

```
<p>@Html.Raw(Model.Description)</p>
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg480740%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

Comment: Just to add to this answer... if you don't use `@Html.Raw()`, any text located in your model objects will be HtmlEncoded, which is currently what is happening and why you're having that issue.

Comment: Yes, by default in MVC view all values are HtmlEncoded.So we need to use @Html.Raw.

Comment: Duh, completely forgot about Html.Raw. That works perfect now, thank you.